# Can you use Google reCAPTCHA v3 without JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, recaptcha

Is there a way to use the Google reCAPTCHA v3 without any JavaScript? I followed many tutorials online such as this one and they all seem to require some JavaScript to make this work.

```
<script>
    grecaptcha.ready(function () {
        grecaptcha.execute('YOUR_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY', { action: 'contact' }).then(function (token) {
            var recaptchaResponse = document.getElementById('recaptchaResponse');
            recaptchaResponse.value = token;
        });
    });
</script>
```

I would like to use this with only HTML and PHP is possible.

https://stevencotterill.com/articles/adding-google-recaptcha-v3-to-a-php-form

Comment: You need JavaScript in some form to work with Google Recaptcha. There might be other captcha solutions that don't have this requirement

Comment: I was able to get v2 to work without JavaScript. So v3 makes JS mandatory?

Comment: reCaptcha comes as a JavaScript library. How could you get it to work without JavaScript?